# index.html not load transpiled javascript from babel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to create a pure ES6 app for studying purposes with node/express as web server. I'm using module imports and it's working fine as you can see in server.js file, but when i use these scripts in index.html he doesn't get the transpiled file and calls 'Uncaught SyntaxError:' My question is, how can i access the transpiled files from index.html?

server.js file:

```
import express from 'express'

const port = 3000
const app = express()

app.set("view options", {layout: false});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/src'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server running in port "+ port)
})
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ntn",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js --exec babel-node"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.8.0"
  }
}
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> ... </head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Word!</h1>
    <script src="pages/member/MemberController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

MemberController.js file:

```
import { MemberView } from 'MemberView'

export class MemberController{

    constructor(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using webpack with babel to transform your ES6 code to ES5 code? Once you setup webpack, there is a loader called "babel-loader" which does the transform for you.